# How to compare versions?

Tags: gradle

```
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
jar.doLast{
    //how to write this block?
    if(version.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")){

    }
    else if(version.endsWith("RELEASE")){
        tasks.obfuscate.execute()
    }
}
```

Need to have obfuscated and non obfuscated versions automatically, instead of doing it by hand every time.

How do I do the conditional checks in gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to trigger execution of task `obfuscate` when building a RELEASE version, you could simplify your script as follows:

```
if(version.endsWith("RELEASE")){
    // add finalizing task to jar task
    jar.finalizedBy obfuscate
}
```

Note that you should not execute tasks from a task execution block , but prefer the use of task dependencies.

You should also avoid putting too much *imperative code* in your scripts, and prefer the use of plugins, as it is well decribed here :  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/authoring_maintainable_build_scripts.html#sec:avoid_imperative_logic_in_scripts